# Ubuntu OpenCV: Program Crashing when loading video file

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu, video, crash

I'm trying to load a video file with opencv in python. The program crashes and returns:

$ python bg_reduction.py
     Segmentation fault (core dumped)

After hours of digging through forums I'm beginning to realize that the problem may be with my build of opencv. I'm a novice programmer and linux user so most of what I've found was over my head anyways.

Here's the gist of my program -- which works when streaming video from webcam, fails when loading from file.

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('SuccessPrint.mp4')                                                               
fgbg = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2()                                                                                                         

while (cap.isOpened()):                                                                                                                             
    try:                                                                                                                                            
        ret, frame = cap.read()                                                                                                                     
    except cv2.error:                                                                                                                               
        cap.release()                                                                                                                               
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()                                                                                                                     

    k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xFF                                                                                                                      
    if k == 27:                                                                                                                                     
        break                                                                                                                                       

cap.release()                                                                                                                                       
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Here is the codec information returned from:

```
$ffmpeg -i SuccessPrint.mp4

Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 557 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 12288 tbn, 48 tbc (default)
```

And finally here is the information from the core:

```
$gdb bg_reduction.py core
```

Returns(I've removed the path):

```
    /bg_reduction2.py": not in executable format: File format not recognized
[New LWP 12398]
[New LWP 12401]
[New LWP 12399]
[New LWP 12400]
Core was generated by `python bg_reduction2.py'.
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x00007fe3c7364fd1 in ?? ()
[Current thread is 1 (LWP 12398)]
(gdb)
```

Any advice would be incredible. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Update: Solved

Problem was the initial build:

```
linux/videodev.h not found
```

Had to run these codes:

```
sudo apt-get install libv4l-dev
cd /usr/include/linux
sudo ln -s ../libv4l1-videodev.h videodev.h
```